# How to make a hashed password like the crypt function does?

Tags: c++, openssl, base64, crypt

I want to generate a hashed password manually using openssl API according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)) of crypt, but the program result is not same with the result from crypt function, is there something wrong?

```
int main() {
    const char *salt = "123456";
    const char *password = "123456";
    unsigned char hashedPasswd[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];


    SHA512_CTX context;
    if (!SHA512_Init(&context)) return -1;
    if (!SHA512_Update(&context, (unsigned char *) salt, strlen(salt))) return -1;
    if (!SHA512_Update(&context, (unsigned char *) password, strlen(password))) return -1;
    if (!SHA512_Final(hashedPasswd, &context)) return -1;

    std::string base64Data = base64_encode(hashedPasswd, sizeof(hashedPasswd));
    printf("my result: %s\n", base64Data.c_str());


    char *hashedPassword = crypt("123456", "$6$123456");
    printf("crypt result: %s\n", hashedPassword);

    return 0;
}
```

My Result:

PXeFkSq39sRSVXsSaxLWUUWDt45I8tw9mgcY8GE3B/r3VylOko0q727qPChy+uibqcFuCy6w67ruaQ3AyHHeDg==

Crypt Result:

$6$123456$37mxvJGRzjWxgD3HYl.bKq4aUXrcYV8mk0pxmqg8ARv3t9ke5ZM/NBbwTkx1FDcnLhrOX3jQc6L/NKAohhQJn/

The part of hashed is quite different.

Comment: Crypt is s lot more complex than that, see https://akkadia.org/drepper/sha-crypt.html

Comment: Hash value mainly varies with prime used in generating the hash.  Maybe your used function and Crypt function didn't used same prime numbers ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles As the hash process of crypt() is particularly specialized，not just to use standard SHA algorithm to hash the plain text with salt and then make it readable by base64, so there is no other way to make the same output as crypt() does except call the function.

Comment: If you follow the link I posted you'll see the implementation of sha512_crypt is around 300 lines once you've stripped out the sha512 implementation, you'll need a similar amount of code if you want to re-implement it. It is not simply a hash of the password and the salt, it is made more complex to deliberately make it slow to compute to make dictionary attacks more difficult